# Checked luggage from Chicago to Bangkok via Shanghai

Tags: transit, luggage, pvg

Will I have to retrieve my checked luggage in Shanghai Pudong airport when traveling from Chicago to Bangkok on Star Alliance airlines with connecting flights?

Comment: Which airlines are you flying with?

Comment: United connecting to Thai Airlines.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your flights are on a single ticket and with interlining airlines, which will be the case if they're Star Alliance, **you do not need to pick up and recheck your luggage**.